# Android: how to get all the dates of the month after selecting the certain month and weekdays?

Tags: java, android, date, dayofweek

I've made a spinner for selecting a certain month, then I've also created some checkbox for choosing certain days, then how can i show all the dates after choosing such information?

E.g. If i choose January and pick Mondays and Wednesdays, how can i show all the dates of Mondays: 2/1,9/1/,16/1,23/1,30/1 and Wednesdays:4/1,11/1,18/1,25/1 respectively?

I'm looking forward to hearing from you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old `Date` and `Calendar` classes have proven to be confusing, flawed, and troublesome. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes in Java 8 and later. See below for links to back-ports for earlier Java and for Android.

## Using java.time

The data behind your which-days-of-the-week checkboxes can be represented using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum. That class provides seven instances, one for each day of the week, Monday-Sunday.

You can collect the user’s desired days in a [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), a special highly-optimized `Set` implementation for [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) objects.

```
Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek = EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class );
daysOfWeek.add( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
daysOfWeek.add( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );
```

Remember the chosen month and year using the `YearMonth` object.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY );  // Or ( 2017 , 1 ) for January.
```

Get the first date of that month, represented as a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 );
```

Loop each day-of-week in our collection. For each, determine the first occurrence of the month. Java provides a handy [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) for that first occurrence. Then add a week at a time until we find ourselves in the next month.

```
for ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek : daysOfWeek ) {
    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<> ( 5 );
    LocalDate ld = firstOfMonth.with ( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth ( 1 , dayOfWeek ) );
    do {
        dates.add ( ld );
        // Set up next loop.
        ld = ld.plusWeeks ( 1 );
    } while ( YearMonth.from ( ld ).equals ( ym ) );  // While in the targeted month.
    System.out.println ( "ym.toString(): " + ym + " | dayOfWeek.toString(): " + dayOfWeek + " | dates: " + dates );
}
```

> ym.toString(): 2017-01 | dayOfWeek.toString(): MONDAY | dates: [2017-01-02, 2017-01-09, 2017-01-16, 2017-01-23, 2017-01-30]
>
> ym.toString(): 2017-01 | dayOfWeek.toString(): WEDNESDAY | dates: [2017-01-04, 2017-01-11, 2017-01-18, 2017-01-25]

See [this code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/IANcaS).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so appreciated that you've given such a great and detailed answer. Yet, i am just a beginner, some codes above are quite new for me.. but i will try to figure out what they are. Thanks!

Comment: @chunyuen2 You can read the [Oracle Tutorial on Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Enums in Java are much more powerful and useful than simple enums found in other languages. And read [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/) if you are new to collections in general and `Set`/`List` specifically.

Comment: @BasilBourquean Can i use this in writing an Android app? As i'm learning to write an Android app by using the Android studio and most of the code are based on the language `java`.

Comment: @chunyuen2 Reread my Answer carefully. Notice the bullet "Android".

Answer (score 1):

With this method you can

```
private String getMondaysOfJanuary() 

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY); // month starts by 0 = january
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String output = "";
        while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
            output += cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + ",";
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
        }
        return output.substring(0, output.length-1);
}
```

Replacing this two lines with yours data and parametrizing this method you can achieve your goal

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just a beginner, so i may need some time to understand the code.

Comment: @chunyuen2  Be aware that the `Calendar` class is very confusing and poorly designed. For many reasons it is now supplanted by the `ZonedDateTime` class and other java.time classes. As a beginner, do not look at `Calendar` as an example of good object-oriented programming; it is more an example of what *not* to do.

Comment: @BasilBourque Truely, i'm quite confused about it.

Comment: hey guys we have used these classes for years. Now there are newer ones, but these are still valid. @chunyuen2 read my code carefully, i'm simply setting the first monday of january then I'm adding 7 days to the calendar instance until the month changes

Comment: @firegloves hi my buddy, thanks again for your reply, but i have another question that what if i pick Monday and Wednesday at the same time.. is it possible to write the code in the same class? 
like this:
`cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY+WEDNESDAY);`

Comment: @firegloves Also, it seems the `+1` from `output += cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + ",";
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);` is the most important part that determines the month even though it is set`cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY)`

Comment: @chunyuen2 you can't do MONDAY+WEDNESDAY because they are constants for predefined int values. Summing them you are referencing to another int value. then for month: months starts from 0 = JANUARY, 1 = FEBRUARY and so on. So if you want to print human readable values you have to add 1 to obtain your desider output format

Comment: @firegloves thanks, i've achieved that by copying the coding and change some variables :)